Name of the bibresource in biblatex for every entry in bibliography
I want to get the name of the .bib file and the bibkey for every bibentry to be printed when using \printbibliography. So far my MWE is as follows:
(The bibkey part is already done. See below.)
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.05cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
    maxbibnames=99,
    style=ieee,
    sorting=ynt,
    defernumbers=true
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{doi}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488948/how-to-magically-add-the-file-field-to-each-entry-in-a-bib-file
% Prints the bibkey for every bib entry.
\DeclareFieldFormat{bibkey}{\path{[#1]}}
\renewbibmacro{finentry}{\printfield[bibkey]{entrykey}\finentry}

\addbibresource{file1.bib}
\addbibresource{file2.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}    
\printbibliography
\end{document}

The file1.bib is given by:
@article{smith2020,
  author = {John Smith},
  title = {A Great Paper},
  journal = {Journal of Important Things},
  year = {2020},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {1--10},
  sourcefile = {mybibfile.bib}
}

@article{doe2020,
  author  = {John Doe},
  title   = {An Interesting Article},
  journal = {Journal of Interesting Stuff},
  year    = {2020},
  volume  = {42},
  number  = {3},
  pages   = {123-456},
}

The file2.bib is given by
@article{source1:entry1,
  author = {Author One},
  title = {Title One},
  journal = {Journal One},
  year = {2020},
}

@article{source2:entry1,
  author = {Author Two},
  title = {Title Two},
  journal = {Journal Two},
  year = {2021},
}

I want all the bib entries to have the following format:
[1] J. Doe, ``An interesting article," Journal of Interesting Stuff, vol. 42, no. 3,
    pp. 123–456, 2020. [doe2020 @ file1.bib]

